# What architecture do VoIP applications use, P2P or Client-Server?

Tags: p2p, voip

Please let me know what architecture do VoIP applications use, P2P or Client-Server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of each in general.  There are three protocols involved, usually.  One of them, for example SIP, is used to establish the connection.  you need a server for that because someone has to establish the original connection; that means advertising availability and such.  The other two are essentially always RTP and RTCP -- "real time protocol" and "real time control protocol", and those are better P2P, because you want fast transmission with no intermediate bottleneck.

There's a [nice article on the whole discussion here](http://www.packetizer.com/ipmc/papers/understanding_voip/voip_protocols.html).

Answer (score 3):

There's usually some kind of "presense server": devices register ("I exist here!") and calls are established via the server (when you say "I want to connect to device **(555) 555-1234**" that connection request is routed via presence servers).

After the call is established and the real-time voice/media is streaming, that traffic is usually peer-to-peer (bypassing any central server), except if there's a complication like both devices being behind firewalls.